# Text Type In TextBox list show in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I need code to use a TextBox to the filter the `product` table in the Northwind database by `productname` database and show the matching `productname`, `unitprice`, `stock` fields in the associated DatagridView control. The grid should update after each change as the user types in the TextBox.

I have this so far:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

    Dim sql1 As String = "SELECT ProductName ,Stock,unitprice from PRODUCT"
    Dim dadosretornados As System.Data.DataTableReader = buscadadosacess(sql1)

    While dadosretornados.Read
        If InStr(dadosretornados("Productname"), TextBox1.Text, CompareMethod.Text) <> 0 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dadosretornados("productname"), dadosretornados("stock"),dadosretornados("unitprice")
        End If
    End While
    oConn.Close()

End Sub
```

[image: screenshot]

When list is showing, the user can select a product with arrow keys and press `Enter` to put the full `productname` in the TextBox.

[More information here.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7ef72cd6-9157-4b69-99eb-f91ee3bf4dc8/textbox-show-list?forum=vsarch)

Comment: We need to see more of the VB.Net code you already have in order to help you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Firstly, how many records are there in total?  If the total number is not too large then it may be advisable to retrieve all the data up front and filter locally.  The downsides include a slow initial load and the possibility of retrieving data you don't need.  The upsides include faster filtering and avoidance of retrieving the same data multiple times.

Comment: Whether you do the filtering locally or by SQL, you should not do so immediately on the change of text.  You should start/restart a `Timer` on the change of text and then filter when it `Ticks`.  That way, if the user intends to enter multiple characters, you won;t needlessly filter multiple times.  It's more important if using SQL but may also improve performance if filtering locally.  You might use an `Interval` in the range 300-500, depending on expected typing speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged


    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()



    Dim sql1 As String = "SELECT ProductName ,Stock,unitprice from PRODUCT"
    Dim dadosretornados As System.Data.DataTableReader = buscadadosacess(sql1)

    While dadosretornados.Read



        If InStr(dadosretornados("Productname"), TextBox1.Text, CompareMethod.Text) <> 0 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dadosretornados("productname"), dadosretornados("stock"),dadosretornados("unitprice")
        End If
    End While
    oConn.Close()

End Sub
```